# create a set of cumulative intersection counts

Tags: r, set, iteration, dataframe

I want to count the intersection of var1[i] and union(var2[1],...,var2[i]).

Using this data

```
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
var2 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:5), '2005' = c(2,3,6), '2006' = 2:3 )
```

I would like to populate a results list with:

> ```
>  1. intersect(var1$2003,var2$2003)
>  2. intersect(var1$2004,union(var2$2003,var2$2004))
>  3. intersect(var1$2005,union(var2$2005(union(var2$2003,var2$2004))))
> ```

and so on, until 2012 (not shown in the example)

- Disclaimer: due to editing, the comments below might not make sense.

Comment: What does `var1[1]` refer to: the first element in `var1` ?

Comment: @mnel: No, the column. Every column here actually refers to a data frame with one column.

Comment: Then perhaps it should be var1[[1]] (or you should define what var1 and var2 in terms of R (not just visually)

Comment: if I replace [] wit [[]] in the assignment above, print(result1) gives me list() ...Not what I would like to get. :(

Comment: I don't usually downvote but am doing so because of the meaningless phrase "retro-cumulative nrow count" and the failure to explain how the "correct answer" was arrived at ... (Not to mention the lack of r code.).

Comment: @DWin, fair enough. I'm currently editing the post to make it more meaningful. Not to be surprised, I'm just starting with R, so that explains why there is no code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you want?

```
# create the data
var1 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:3), '2005' = c(6,4,1), '2006' = 1:4 )
var2 <- list('2003' = 1:3, '2004' = c(4:5), '2005' = c(2,3,6), '2006' = 2:3 )

# A couple of nested lapply statements

lapply(setNames(seq_along(var1), names(var1)), 
   function(i,l1,l2) length(intersect(l1[[i]], Reduce(union,l2[1:i]))), 
  l1 = var1,l2=var2)

$`2003`
[1] 3

$`2004`
[1] 2

$`2005`
[1] 3

$`2006`
[1] 4
```

note that `Reduce(union,var2)`reduces the list `var2` by successively combining the elements using `union` (see `?Reduce`)

```
Reduce(union,var2)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

## EDIT elegant alternative

use the `accumulate = T` argument in `Reduce`

```
lapply(mapply(intersect,var1, Reduce(union, var2, accumulate=T)),length)
```

Because --

```
Reduce(union, var2, accumulate = T)

## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped us moving forward. But intersect(var1$2005, union(var2$2005, var$2004, var2$2003) = 3, and your result evaluates '2005' to 2 instead. Hence, this is still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want `union(var2$2003,var2$2004)` as your question asks or  `union(var2$2005, var2$2004, var2$2003)` as your comment suggests.

Comment: We're very close now, @mnel. What I need (and it might not be clear in the original question) is to populate the results list with: intersect(var1$2003,var2$2003); intersect(var1$2004,union(var2$2003,var2$2004)); intersect(var1$2005,union(var2$2005(union(var2$2003,var2$2004)))); and so on, until 2012 (not shown in the example)...

Comment: The question does make more sense now. And there is a more elegant solution